# How to change Word.Range text without losing format

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, add-in, text-formatting

Anyone knows how can I change the text of a Word.Range object but still keeping it's format?
For example if I have "this **text**" and I change it to "that **txt**", txt will still be in bold.

I'm looking for a way to change the whole text of the range, not just a single word, as I'm getting the new text from an independent API, I can assume that the new text and the old text have the same number of words.

This is what I got so far:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < oldWords.Length; i++)
    {
        if (oldWords[i] == newWords[i])
            continue;

        object Replace = WdReplace.wdReplaceOne;
        object FindText = oldWords[i];
        object ReplaceWith = newWords[i];
        var success = Sentence.Find.Execute(parameters stub);
    }
```

But for some reason, it only succeeds in the first Execute, because the range selection remains on the found word.

Edit: got it, after each execute, I had restore the original end position of my Range.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `Execute` method to change the text with formatting.
You can do it like:

```
Range rng=doc.Content;
rng.Find.Execute(ref finding, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing)

//if this method returns true, you will get the range at the finding location.
if(rng.Find.Found)
{
  rng.Text='sth';
  rng.Bold=0;
}
```

Maybe this can help you.